# How to remove page break after \part in report/book

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, parts

I have tried to look through, but I couldn't find a clear solution on this.

I have a document that uses `report` with multiple `\chapter`s in multiple `\part`s as:

```
\part{foo}
\chapter{uno}
\chapter{dos}
\part{bar}...
```

This results in an entire page that is "Part I Uno". I would like to remove the page break, and have both part foo, and chapter uno on the same page as:

```
Part I foo
Chapter 1 Uno
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `chapter` produces also a page break. However you can use a package like `titlesec`.

Comment: [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package is what you search for, as Marco suggests. The page break can be manually removed by some "low-level" tweak (you can locally redefine the command that makes the page break), but it is really not a nice solution to this.

Answer (score 23):

With the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, you could define a "title class" without pagebreak:

```
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
```

Title classes are:

- `page`: a single page like a book part page
- `top`: starts a page and places the heading at the top
- `straight`: titles in the text, such as by `\section`

A full example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\centering\partname\ \thepart}{20pt}{\Huge\centering}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\begin{document}
\part{foo}
\chapter{uno}
\end{document}
```

[image: part and chapter heading]

Comment: I was hesitating to go the titlesec route, but this works well, and I am enjoying the flexibility of the package. A follow up question...this removes the page break at the end of the chapter. So a new part/chapter starts on the same page of the text as the previous chapter. I could use something like /eject and start a new page, but is there a nicer way to keep the page-break at the end of the chapter?

Comment: @Elmasto: use the `top` class for parts starting on new pages. I updated my answer.

Comment: this does not work work with komascript(scrbook)

Answer (score 13):

To achieve your objective *without* loading a package such as `titlesec`, one must (i) modify the command `\@endpart` and (ii) change the `\chapter` command because it, too, inserts a page break by default. Although you didn't specify this explicitly, I further assume that you (iii) want to have the "Part xx" material placed at the *top* of the page rather than in the middle. By the way, I assume that your document is set in "onecolumn" rather than in "twocolumn" mode. Taking care of the twocolumn case isn't all that more difficult, but it does add some overhead which I gather isn't required here.

The following code shows how to do this for the case of the **report** document class. Note that I've created a command called `\nonewpagechapter` and have left the standard `\chapter` command untouched. That way, you can still use the `\chapter` command for all those occasions when you *do* want the chapter to start on a new page. Of course, if `\nonewpagechapter` is too wordy for your taste, you can give it a more succinct name, such as `\nchapter`...

```
\documentclass{report}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% First, modify the \@endpart macro.
\def\@endpart{} 

% Next, copy the \chapter macro to \nonewpagechapter, and ...
% ... suppress page-breaking instructions in the modified macro
\let\nonewpagechapter\chapter 
\patchcmd\nonewpagechapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}

% Third, suppress vertical whitespace before "Part xx" material
\patchcmd{\part}{\null\vfil}{}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{foo}
\nonewpagechapter{Uno} % starts on same page as "Part I ... foo" header
\chapter{Dos}          % starts on a new page
\part{bar}             % starts on a new page
\nonewpagechapter{Tres}% starts on same page as "Part II ... bar" header
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum** If someone were using the **scrbook** (Koma-Script book) document class instead of the **report** document class, he/she would have to replace the command

```
\patchcmd{\part}{\null\vfil}{}{}{}
```

with

```
\patchcmd{\part}{\partheadstartvskip}{}{}{}
```

in order to suppress the insertion of extra whitespace above the "Part xx" line. The other patch commands could be used without modification.

Comment: +1 for adding `\nonewpagechapter`.

Comment: I liked the idea of modifying the existing commands, but I am having a hard time compiling this (pdflatex). It says 'use of \@ doesn't match definition'.

Comment: I added a blank line before `\makeatletter`. The MWE should compile now.

Comment: I have tried your answer with koma script (a example is here: http://pastebin.com/JCKXvzhu), and the problem I have is that the part starts very low on the page. (In the example at about have the page, but in longer documents, it might even start lower). Do you know a fix for that?

Comment: @user8868: Do note that my answer was geared to the **report** document class, as that's what the OP specified.  Which one of the koma-script classes are you using? Any adaptation of the code I've provided will depend on the document class in use.

Comment: I use scrbook, more or less like in the code example on pastebin.

Comment: @user8868 -- to get the code working with the `scrbook` document class, all you need to do is to change the instruction `\patchcmd{\part}{\null\vfil}{}{}{}` to `\patchcmd{\part}{\partheadstartvskip}{}{}{}`. This is the case because the `\part` command is implemented quite differently in the `scrbook` and `report` document classes. Interestingly, the other patching commands needn't be modified. Do note, by the way, that more commands would have to be modified if the `twocolumn` option were in force. (However, judging from your notes, this does not seem to be the case for your document.)