# report - headings of part/chapter on same page and each of them on same line

Tags: chapters, titlesec, parts, report

I am using the report document class and would like to have part and chapter headings on the same page and each of the headings on the same line. I already found a solution to have the two headings on the same page but failed to find a way to put each of the headings on the same line. Does someone know how I have to change my MWE below so looks like this:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thepart}{20pt}{\Huge\centering}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-11pt}{11pt}

\begin{document}

\part{part heading}

\chapter{chapter heading}

text starts here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your desired example shows part and chapter headings on different lines, not on the same line.

Comment: I changed the explanation of my problem a bit. Hope it is clearer now?

Comment: I eventually found a solution to my problem here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42527/146654