# How to prevent /part from skipping a page, or what else could I use instead

Tags: miktex, titles, texmaker, parts

I'm still relatively new to LaTeX as I switched after having too many problems with Microsoft Word. I'm required to write a document with very precise requirements at the beginning of the document that are making me confuse. Currently, from my table of content and chapter 1, everything seems fine, but I need some "meta" chapters to come between the cover and the content, kind of prefaces.

My first though was to use Part()

```
\part*(First preface)
text
\part*(Second preface)
text....
```

Current problem is that I get "First preface title", but then the text is on the next page, I would like the title to appear on top of the page and the text to start just after.

I dont really know if it's important that the title appears as a part.
It could just some kind of title (I tried `\title` but it's apparently only for the document title not some kind of headings.)

(Using TexMaker 5.0.4/Windows 10 and MiKTex 2.9 )

Comment: Why don't you simply use `\chapter*` for your prefaces?

Comment: Thanks, I think I had indeed tried \chapter or some other levels but I didn't think of testing it with the "*" ... It seems indeed cleaner than the workaround I've post in the answers so if you post this as answer I could select it as solution.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for a simple suggestion, unless you have some specific requirements.

Comment: You may need to [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42526/how-to-remove-page-break-after-part-in-report-book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42526/how-to-remove-page-break-after-part-in-report-book).

Comment: `\part` acts like a super-chapter, so it doesn't sound like that's what you want.  What are the requirements of these "meta" chapters?  Adding the `*` to `\chapter` (or `\section`) makes it no longer numbered, which is usually the desired outcome in the preface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem for now.

```
\centerline{\textbf{First preface title}}
Text...
\blankpage
\centerline{\textbf{Second preface title}}
Text...
\blankpage
```

I hoped for a cleaner solution but this one is at least satisfying. I still need to tweak a bit to add some space between preface titles and text, and to make titles a larger.

StackExchange won't let me select this solution for I think two days so I'm still accepting better solutions.