# Minitoc on Koma-script (scrbook) class with greek language

Tags: koma-script, greek, minitoc

I'm making a book with the koma-script (scrbook) class and I need to add a minitoc at the start of every part and chapter.
I found a solution [with this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516093/replacement-minitoc-package-style-by-koma-script-possibilities), however it doesn't work with the greek language from babel.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,open=any,twocolumn]{scrbook}[2019/10/12]% needs version 3.27 or newer

\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\providecommand*{\Ifstr}{\ifstr}% added because of changes in upcoming KOMA-Script version 3.28 and \ifstr replaced by \Ifstr in the code (see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif) 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{scrwfile}% avoid trouble with the limited number of write handles
\usepackage{xpatch}

\colorlet{partcolor}{blue}
\addtokomafont{partprefix}{\color{partcolor}}% change color of part prefix
\addtokomafont{part}{\normalcolor}% use normal color for part title
%\renewcommand*\partformat{\partname~\thepart}% if you want to remove \autodot from the definition
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocdynnumwidth=true,%
  tocbeforeskip=1em,
  tocindent=1.5em
]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocbeforeskip=1em plus 1pt minus 1pt,% add some glue
  toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=\baselineskip,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocindent=1.5em,
  tocnumwidth=3.5em
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.75\baselineskip,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocindent=3.8em,
  tocnumwidth=4em
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip,
  tocindent=7em,
  tocnumwidth=4.1em
]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=10em,
  tocnumwidth=5em
]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=12em,
  tocnumwidth=6em
]{subparagraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommands
  [tocpagenumberwidth=3em]
  {part,chapter,section,subsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502077
\makeatletter
\newif\ifuseparttoc
\newcommand*{\parttoc}[1][\thepart]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
  \useparttoctrue% switch on part-toc-entries
  \edef\ext@parttoc{tcp#1}% extension of the part-toc-file, e.g., tcpI
  \DeclareNewTOC[
    listname=Obsah,
    %unset=onecolumn% if the part toc should use twocolumn
  ]{\ext@parttoc}% declare a new toc file
  \begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=\chaptertocdepth% we want entries down to chapter
    \listoftoc{\ext@parttoc}% show the toc with header
  \endgroup
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifuseparttoc% if part toc entries should be generated
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@parttoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\part{\useparttocfalse}{}{}% entries in part toc are automatically switched off at start of \part
\newif\ifusechaptertoc% Switch to tell \addtocentrydefault to not only make entries to the toc-file but also to the current section-toc-file
\newcommand*{\chaptertoc}[2][\thechapter]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
  \usechaptertoctrue% switch on chapter-toc-entries
  \edef\ext@chaptoc{tcc#1}% extension of the chapter-toc-file, e.g., tcc1
  \DeclareNewTOC{\ext@chaptoc}% declare a new toc file
  %\addsec*{Contents}% header of the chaptertoc
  \setchapterpreamble{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \hrulefill\par
      \value{tocdepth}=\subsectiontocdepth% we want entries down to subsection
      \listoftoc*{\ext@chaptoc}% show the toc without header
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\bigskip\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill\par
    \bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces% add some vertical space after the toc and do not indent the following text
  }%
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifusechaptertoc% if chapter toc entries should be generated
    \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{}
      {\expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@chaptoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\chapter{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% entries in chapter toc are automatically switched off at start of \chapter
\xpretocmd\part{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% entries in chapter toc are automatically switched off at start of \part
\makeatother

\newcommand\setchaptertoc[1][]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc}}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc[#1]}}%
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\partnumdepth}% depth of TOC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{3000}
\setcounter{chapter}{100}
\setcounter{part}{5080}

\part{Part I}
\parttoc

\setchaptertoc
\chapter{My chapter I}
\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\subsection{My first subsection}
\blindtext
\section{My second section}
\blindtext

\chapter{My chapter II}
\chapter{My chapter II}
\chapter{My chapter III}
\chapter{My chapter IV}
\chapter{My chapter V}
\chapter{My chapter VI}
\chapter{My chapter VII}
\chapter{My chapter VIII}
\chapter{My chapter IX}
\chapter{My chapter X}
\chapter{My chapter XI}
\chapter{My chapter XII}
\chapter{My chapter XIII}
\chapter{My chapter XIV}
\chapter{My chapter XV}
\chapter{My chapter XVI}
\chapter{My chapter XVII}
\chapter{My chapter XVIII}
\chapter{My chapter XIX}
\chapter{My chapter XX}
\chapter{My chapter XXI}
\chapter{My chapter XXII}
\chapter{My chapter XXIII}
\chapter{My chapter XXIV}
\chapter{My chapter XXVI}
\chapter{My chapter XXVII}
\chapter{My chapter XXVIII}
\chapter{My chapter XXIX}
\chapter{My chapter XXX}

\part{Part II}
\parttoc
\setchaptertoc
\chapter{My chapter I}
\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\subsection{My first subsection}
  \blindtext
\section{My second section}
\blindtext:

\end{document}
```

This puts an error

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 127.
<inserted text> 
                \fi
```

Using the polutonikogreek language instead of the greek language puts the same error.
I suspect that this is related to the [Ifstr\ifstr problem in KomaScript](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/Warning_Deprecated_if/) but when the greek language works in a complete book, it doesn't bear this minitoc approach?
I need to write some sentences in greek, not the complete book.

Comment: The error appears with pdflatex. It does not with xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: Thanks you Simon, I confirm. However, for the moment, I can't compile the complete book with xelatex or lulatex. Maybe is there a solution with pdflatex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\usepackage[greek]{babel}` and PDFLaTeX `\@Roman` is no longer expandable and not suitable to be used as part of a filename, because it contains font switching commands. A simple suggestion would be, to not use `\thepart` but `\the\c@part` to build the extensions of the part contents auxiliary files:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,open=any,twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrwfile}% avoid trouble with the limited number of write handles
\usepackage{xpatch}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502077
\makeatletter
\newif\ifuseparttoc
\newcommand*{\parttoc}[1][\the\c@part]{% CHANGED
  \useparttoctrue% switch on part-toc-entries
  \edef\ext@parttoc{tcp#1}% extension of the part-toc-file, e.g., tcp1
  \DeclareNewTOC[
    listname=Obsah,
    %unset=onecolumn% if the part toc should use twocolumn
  ]{\ext@parttoc}% declare a new toc file
  \begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=\chaptertocdepth% we want entries down to chapter
    \listoftoc{\ext@parttoc}% show the toc with header
  \endgroup
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifuseparttoc% if part toc entries should be generated
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@parttoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\part{\useparttocfalse}{}{}% entries in part toc are automatically switched off at start of \part
\newif\ifusechaptertoc% Switch to tell \addtocentrydefault to not only make entries to the toc-file but also to the current section-toc-file
\newcommand*{\chaptertoc}[2][\thechapter]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
  \usechaptertoctrue% switch on chapter-toc-entries
  \edef\ext@chaptoc{tcc#1}% extension of the chapter-toc-file, e.g., tcc1
  \DeclareNewTOC{\ext@chaptoc}% declare a new toc file
  %\addsec*{Contents}% header of the chaptertoc
  \setchapterpreamble{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \hrulefill\par
      \value{tocdepth}=\subsectiontocdepth% we want entries down to subsection
      \listoftoc*{\ext@chaptoc}% show the toc without header
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\bigskip\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill\par
    \bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces% add some vertical space after the toc and do not indent the following text
  }%
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifusechaptertoc% if chapter toc entries should be generated
    \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{}
      {\expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@chaptoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\chapter{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% entries in chapter toc are automatically switched off at start of \chapter
\xpretocmd\part{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% entries in chapter toc are automatically switched off at start of \part
\makeatother

\newcommand\setchaptertoc[1][]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc}}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc[#1]}}%
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\partnumdepth}% depth of TOC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part I}
\parttoc
\setchaptertoc
\chapter{My chapter I}
\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\subsection{My first subsection}
\blindtext
\section{My second section}
\blindtext

\chapter{My chapter II}
\chapter{My chapter II}
\chapter{My chapter III}

\part{Part II}
\parttoc
\setchaptertoc
\chapter{My chapter I}
\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\subsection{My first subsection}
  \blindtext
\section{My second section}
\blindtext:

\end{document}
```

But note: If you somewhere switch the part numbering, this would not work. However, because of the optional argument of `\parttoc` you can alternatively use the original definition and use the optional argument, e.g. `\parttoc[I]` or `\parttoc[examples]`.

Another alternative would be to locally redefine `\ensureascii` (and do this also for chapters) while building the file extension:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,open=any,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrwfile}% avoid trouble with the limited number of write handles
\usepackage{xpatch}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359758
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502077
\makeatletter
\newif\ifuseparttoc
\newcommand*{\parttoc}[1][\thepart]{% new command to generate and show a part toc
  \useparttoctrue% switch on part-toc-entries
  \begingroup
    \let\ensureascii\@firstofone% Don't switch encoding or font
    \xdef\ext@parttoc{tcp#1}% extension of the part-toc-file, e.g., tcpI
  \endgroup
  \DeclareNewTOC[
    listname=Obsah,
    %unset=onecolumn% if the part toc should use twocolumn
  ]{\ext@parttoc}% declare a new toc file
  \begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=\chaptertocdepth% we want entries down to chapter
    \listoftoc{\ext@parttoc}% show the toc with header
  \endgroup
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifuseparttoc% if part toc entries should be generated
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@parttoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\part{\useparttocfalse}{}{}% entries in part toc are automatically switched off at start of \part
\newif\ifusechaptertoc% Switch to tell \addtocentrydefault to not only make entries to the toc-file but also to the current section-toc-file
\newcommand*{\chaptertoc}[2][\thechapter]{% new command to generate and show a chapter toc
  \usechaptertoctrue% switch on chapter-toc-entries
  \begingroup
    \let\ensureascii\@firstofone% Don't switch encoding or font
    \xdef\ext@chaptoc{tcc#1}% extension of the chapter-toc-file, e.g., tcc1
  \endgroup
  \DeclareNewTOC{\ext@chaptoc}% declare a new toc file
  %\addsec*{Contents}% header of the chaptertoc
  \setchapterpreamble{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \hrulefill\par
      \value{tocdepth}=\subsectiontocdepth% we want entries down to subsection
      \listoftoc*{\ext@chaptoc}% show the toc without header
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\bigskip\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill\par
    \bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces% add some vertical space after the toc and do not indent the following text
  }%
}
\xapptocmd\addtocentrydefault{% patch the KOMA-Script's generic toc entry generator
  \ifusechaptertoc% if chapter toc entries should be generated
    \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{}
      {\expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@chaptoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}}% do it
  \fi
}{}{}
\xpretocmd\chapter{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% entries in chapter toc are automatically switched off at start of \chapter
\xpretocmd\part{\usechaptertocfalse}{}{}% entries in chapter toc are automatically switched off at start of \part
\makeatother

\newcommand\setchaptertoc[1][]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc}}
    {\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{\chaptertoc[#1]}}%
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\partnumdepth}% depth of TOC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part I}
\parttoc
\setchaptertoc
\chapter{My chapter I}
\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\subsection{My first subsection}
\blindtext
\section{My second section}
\blindtext

\chapter{My chapter II}
\chapter{My chapter II}
\chapter{My chapter III}

\part{Part II}
\parttoc
\setchaptertoc
\chapter{My chapter I}
\section{My first section}
\blindtext
\subsection{My first subsection}
  \blindtext
\section{My second section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

This would also fix similar issues with `\@Alph` or `\@alph`, e.g., if you have an appendix.

Note also: I've removed some code only to minimize the example a little more.

However, instead of the shown suggestion, I would suggest to use LuaLaTeX and also to remove the experimental package `scrwfile`. The KOMA-Script manual also suggests to use LuaLaTeX to avoid the “No room for new write” issue.

Comment: That's great @cabohah, thanks!
What to do if I want the summary of the chapters falls just under the part title (no page break) and if I don't want a title to this list of chapters?
The script doesn't work if I deactivate listname. And if I don't want a page break after a part, I can use the [Mico script.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42528/167347) but it isn't useful here, is it?